# Approach pivoting a T-Table

Tags: r, excel, pivot, tidyverse

I want to pivot a t-table, where you usually look up the sum-scores of a finished questionnare and read the corresponding T-Value in the leftmost column. For some further excel operations e.g. VLOOKUP() i need the tables as shown in the 2nd picture. (data is not exact the same, its from another worksheet)

All possible sum-scores need to be in the leftmost column and the according t-value should be in the corresponding column right of it.

I dont know where to start.
I tried grouping the ua columns and pivoting like

```
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("ua"), 
               values_to = "Score") %>%
  arrange(desc(Score))
```

but this creates some other colums treated as factors and surely not the expected output. Further complicating matters is the presence of NA-Values.
Any advises?

I uploaded the xlsx.file to we-transfer
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/783d404d25fef64fbaf3c8c2dbbe17d120240204224649/7d5f70

[image: The raw file]
[image: This is what i want to get]

Comment: I suspect most others will be reluctant to download the .xlsx file, and [images of data are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Would it be possible share data.frames after you have read in the data from Excel? Using `dput` could you share in your post at least first 10 rows or so of each? If not, perhaps creating a simple toy dataset that would represent the problem? Perhaps you can use a rolling closest join if you want a tidyverse solution.

Comment: thanks for the reply, ill update my code when ive got some more time